# Meteor Collections - 'this' undefined after collection update

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am using a form to save some 'settings' to a Meteor collection (in the example below 'SettingsCollection').

Because there are a *lot* of settings, I am using a trick that I must have found here on stackoverflow, namely, grabbing the collection in a variable (call 'settings'), deleting the ._id, editing, and then using the updated variable to update the collection.

However, this has the effect of messing with 'this':

```
Template.settings_edit.events({
  'submit form': function(e, t) {

    var settings = this // 'THIS' BEING THE DATA CONTEXT        
    var settings_id = this._id
    console.log('settings_id: ', settings_id)  //RETURNS _ID AS EXPECTED

    settings.x = new_x  
    settings.y = new_y
    settings.z = new_z
    settings.a = new_a
    // ...
    // etc.

    delete settings._id // MAKES THE COLLECTION 'HEADLESS' SO THAT I CAN USE IT FOR THE UPDATE BELOW

    SettingsCollection.update(settings_id, { $set: settings })     
    console.log('this._id: ', this._id)  // RETURNS UNDEFINED.  WHAT HAPPENED TO 'THIS'???    
    return false;
   }
})
```

My question is - what happened to 'this'?

It is definitely affected by the line delete settings._id (and I can't think why).

Is there another way to achieve the same update (bearing in mind LOTS OF SETTINGS) that is equally cunning and succinct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you set settings = this and objects are assigned by reference, meaning if you change this, settings changes too and vice versa. 
Same thing goes for arrays.

This wouldn't happen for String, Number and boolean which are assigned by value.

Comment: Aha.  Quite right.  I can, however, achieve the same result by using an empty object e.g. 
    var new_settings = {}, new_settings.a = new_a etc.)